# Can't find the create new application button or link

Tags: facebook

I am having problems trying to create a new facebook canvas page.  I have been following the tutorial: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

It first says to "Start by visit the developer app." which points to: http://developers.facebook.com/apps.  However when I click on this link, it redirects me to to the admin panel of my actual Facebook Page.

I don't understand why this is happening and I don't know of any other means of navigating to where I can create new app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got there:

1. Clicked on your link.
2. Logged into facebook.
3. It brought up the screen below.

I do want to note that it changed the link to a secure link https://developers.facebook.com/apps

[image: This is what I get when I go to that link.]